# Terraform delete the existing EC2 instane on aws when again apply

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

does anyone know if Terraform will wipe out existing resources on AWS?

For example if I already have an existing VPC with resources, or S3/EFS storage will Terraform ignore these resources when I run it with my configuration files to deploy say another VPC?

Or as Terraform is looking for a desired state will it wipe anything existing?

Am hoping unless you specifically import existing resources Terraform will just leave them alone?

Thanks

Comment: It won't wipe anything existing since it stores the state of applied infrastructure, I would recommend reading more documentation on terraform to clarify things and try to do a POC.

Answer (score 0):

So, if terraform is holding a state of the existing resources that you have deployed in a VPC, and you change the value of for example vpc-id; this will cause terrraform to delete your resources and create a new one (since you tell the terraform desired state to be changed). 
However; using the same code is fine. As long as the resources you want to exist in another VPC holds their own state.
There is of course ways to make sure that you can hold the state of resources that is supposed to live in two VPC in the same state, but that might be more confusing for you and I would recommend keeping different deployment in a separate states.

But upon reading your question again, I now understand that you don't have resources in a VPC that is tracked with a terraform state.
So, unless you import resources, the state is not aware about any of the resources (or their unique ID's that AWS keeps for all their resources), terraform can't effect it.

(I'll keep the top answer to me reading your question wrong just in case)